# Automate Elasticsearch index creation on django app startup

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, automation, startup

I want to automatically check and create (if not existing) the elasticsearch index of my  app on startup, this is my current situation which is not working:

```
echo "Checking if Elasticsearch index is setup"
{
cat <<EOF | python /manage.py shell
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
HOST_URLS = ["elasticsearch:9200"]
es_conn = Elasticsearch(HOST_URLS)
INDEX_NAME = "posts"
res = es_conn.indices.exists(index=INDEX_NAME)

if res == True:
  print("Elasicsearch index seems already setup, skipping")
else:
  print("Elasicsearch index not setup yet, creating ...")
  import subprocess
  subprocess.Popen("y | python manage.py search_index --rebuild", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[
                0].decode('utf-8').strip()
EOF
}>/dev/null
```

which again results in:

> "the '{}' indexes? [n/Y]: ".format(", ".join(index_names)))
>   | EOFError: EOF when reading a line

python manage.py search_index --rebuild comes from: https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with running that command and I realized when I tried running manually that it was prompting to ask

```
Are you sure you want to delete the 'clubs' indexes? [n/Y]:
```

This meant that when it was being run automatically, it wasn't getting an answer which crashed everything. You need to add the -f flag to the end of your command which will basically just bypass it from asking this prompt. For example:
`python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f`